# How to get ripple from Nano Ledger S?

Tags: ripple, ledger-hardware-wallet

About five month ago I purchased and put around 2,000 ripple on my Nano Ledger S. I never upgraded the firmware. I can log in to Nano Ledger just fine.

The problem is when I open the desktop application, the desktop application throws this error

[image]

I do not have chrome browser open. Also the browser setting are set to off.

**I'm very frustrated. Are my ripple on my ledger? How can I get them? Please HELP HELP HELP !!!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ripple. But generally, update the firmware and the Ledger Ripple app on the device. Your funds will be safe during these operations. Try again and report back.